# Migrate from Javafx2.2 to Javafx8

Tags: fxml, javafx-8

I am trying to migrate Javafx2.2 application to Javafx8. I am getting following issue while using nested `FXML`:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set.
Use method setRoot() before load.
```

FXML file:

```xml
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" 
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
         xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
         fx:controller="com.ui.TestController">
    <TextField fx:id="textField"/>
    <Button text="Click Me"/>
</fx:root>
```

Code:

```java
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setResources(bundle);
InputStream in = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fxml);
loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource(fxml));
Node page = null;
try {
    page = (Node) loader.load(in);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("{}", e);
} finally {
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("{}", e);
    }
}
```

I need `page` node to set in another `BorderPane.center`. It works with Javafx2.2. What I am missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this code from TestController? Or from another controller? Where is the mentioned nesting of FXML?

Comment: I added this snippet in one util function. It takes argument `String fxml` (Path to new fxml) and bundle, and returns `Node` which I attach  with `BorderPane.center`. `BoarderPane.left` contains `menu`- by clicking on that menu I need to add that `Node` to `BorderPane.center`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `<VBox></VBox>` instead of `<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox"></fx:root>` has fixed this issue, atleast for Javafx build `b121`.