# Root hasn't been set Error with Java 8 Eclipse

Tags: java, macos, javafx, javafx-8, java-8

Recently I installed Java 8 build 124 for my JavaFX application and I started getting these errors:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.
/Users/jonathan/Projects/Dominion/target/classes/dominion/application/controller/main_overview_tab.fxml:13

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2613)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$RootElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1320)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at dominion.application.controller.MainOverviewTab.initView(MainOverviewTab.java:64)
at dominion.application.controller.MainOverviewTab.initializeController(MainOverviewTab.java:55)
at dominion.application.controller.GameSetupController.<init>(GameSetupController.java:37)
at dominion.application.controller.DashboardController.<init>(DashboardController.java:40)
at dominion.application.controller.MainController.<init>(MainController.java:37)
at dominion.application.Dominion.start(Dominion.java:18)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.
/Users/jonathan/Projects/Dominion/target/classes/dominion/application/controller/players_tab.fxml:13

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2613)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$RootElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1320)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at dominion.application.controller.PlayersTab.initView(PlayersTab.java:46)
```

My application works just fine under Java 7 builds 40 and 51, but not under Java 8 build 124. Here are the first few lines of my main_overview_tab.fxml file:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" id="AnchorPane" fx:id="content" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
<children>
<VBox prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
  <children>
    <HBox prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
        <VBox id="playersVBox" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" spacing="40.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
          <children>
            <Label text="Players">
              <font>
                <Font size="18.0" fx:id="x3" />
              </font>
              <VBox.margin>
                <Insets />
              </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
```

This question is very similar, but didn't seem to help my situation: [JavaFX SceneBuilder 2.0 doesn't open FXML for custom components with fx:root as main layout tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19972735/1359765).

**EDIT**: Code to load FXML

```
public class MainOverviewTab extends Tab implements IObserver {
  @FXML public AnchorPane content;

  private SingleGameSettings gameSettings;
  private List<ImageView> overviewImages;

  public MainOverviewTab() {
  }

  public void initializeController(SingleGameSettings gameSettings) {
      this.gameSettings = gameSettings;
      this.gameSettings.registerObserver(this);

      initView();
  }

  private void initView() {
      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main_overview_tab.fxml"));
      fxmlLoader.setRoot(content);
      fxmlLoader.setController(this);

      try {
          fxmlLoader.load();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      this.setText("Overview Game");
      this.setContent(content);

  }
  ...
```

Comment: Show the java code to load the fxml

Comment: Removing <fx:root> from fxml solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21076712/3231870

Answer (score 30, accepted):

uncheck fx:root construct from Scene Builder-> Document -> Controller, or remove  from code of fxml file

[image: fx:root contruct]

Comment: it is working i removed unchecked from scene builder

Comment: it also worked for me. just make sure to perform Project > Clean.. on Eclipse. Thanks!